# Accord dans "Le point fort de cette application sont ses exercices"

Tags: grammaire, verbes, accord

Dans un [article](http://www.lemonde.fr/campus/article/2017/05/29/cinq-applications-pour-ameliorer-son-anglais_5135616_4401467.html) du *Monde*:

> Le point fort de cette application sont ses exercices de grammaire.

Il y a un désaccord entre le sujet (*Le point*) et le verbe (*sont*). De l'autre côté, on pourrait voir plutôt *ses exercices de grammaire* comme sujet, et il n'y aurait pas de problème.

La phrase est-elle bien écrite du point de vue de la grammaire? Y a-t-il des formulations meilleures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour moi cette phrase n'est pas correcte.

Si l'on suit les règles de grammaire habituelles, le verbe s'accorde avec le sujet.

> Le point fort de cette application ***est*** ses exercices de grammaire.

À noter que « ses exercices de grammaire » est considéré comme un complément du verbe (un attribut du sujet). Quand l'attribut du sujet est un adjectif, il s'accorde avec le sujet, comme le verbe. Quand c'est un nom, il peut prendre un nombre sémantique, comme ici.

Toutefois le rapprochement d'un verbe au singulier avec un attribut au pluriel est un peu gênant. Dans la langue parlée (et quelquefois à l'écrit), on dit en général :

> Le point fort de cette application***, ce sont*** ses exercices de grammaire.

Le pronom *ce* peut être singulier ou pluriel, suivant sa sémantique. Ici, il désigne les exercices de grammaire, donc il est pluriel. « Le point fort … » est un sujet en apposition, qui n'a pas besoin d'être accordé avec quoi que ce soit.

Answer (score 5):

Precisely. You can switch around the two parts, making the plural subject:

> = Ses ***exercices*** de grammaire ***sont*** le point fort de cette application.

If you want to keep the original word order, you can also say:

> = Le point fort de cette application, ***ce sont*** ses exercices de grammaire.

Just how it works in English too, it would be better style to place a *money shot* at the end of the sentence, thereby highlighting the important piece of information and keeping the reader in suspense. The idea « ses exercices de grammaire » is the name of the game here, hence this *reverse* order.

> Le point fort de cette application sont ***ses exercices de grammaire***. {= the money shot}

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? As a native I consider the sentence to be incorrect. It should be either "le point fort est ses exercices" or "le point fort, ce sont. The verb agrees with the subject, and that's "le point fort": "exercices" is an *attribut du sujet*. With "ce", the verb is "sont" because *ce* is grammatically plural when it is semantically plural (and even then it could be "c'est" in colloquial French).

Comment: *Le Monde*'s web edition is not very well proofread. Often the paper edition has more typos fixed and I'm not sure if they always update the web page.

Answer (score 5):

Cette phrase ne me choque pas plus que ça.

C'est une [syllepse selon le nombre](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse). En gros parfois c'est grammaticalement correct, parfois c'est une figure de style, parfois c'est une déformation courante du langage (acceptée ou non).

> "*Le propre de la syllepse, qui apporte un accord sémantique en remplacement d’un accord grammatical, est d’être à la limite de ce qui est fautif ou acceptable, voire couramment lexicalisé, adopté par la langue.*"

Pour moi c'est du langage courant. Ce n'est pas irréprochable, mais ça reste fréquent en journalisme.

(D'ailleurs les journalistes utilisent fréquemment des [formulations à la limite du correct](http://mobile.agoravox.fr/tribune-libre/article/la-langue-francaise-malmenee-par-128029), participant à les populariser)

Comment: La syllepse m'a l'air d'être le genre de justification permettant de faire a peu près n'importe quoi. A ce compte là, n'importe quel langage oral peut donc s'écrire tel qu'exprimé sous prétexte de "syllepse" ?

Comment: @xhaltar Non, ça exprime seulement un désaccord entre le sujet et un verbe ou un complément. Il ne peut y avoir de syllepse que de genre, de nombre, ou les deux. La syllepse selon le cas grammatical reste selon le nombre à mon sens (en tout cas au vu des exemples de la page). Ça reste une erreur, mais il y a un désaccord entre sujet et complètement dans tous les cas.

Comment: @xhaltar Par exemple on devrait dire "*la plupart des gens a tort*", mais on dit souvent "*la plupart des gens **ont** tort*", parce qu'on pense à "*les gens ont tort*", et que de toute façon "*la plupart*" désigne toujours plusieurs personnes. On fait passer le discours avant les règles grammaticales, car c'est plus naturel ou plus simple à comprendre. Autre exemple : "*La plupart des parents **sont** venus chercher leurs enfants après le spectacle*". La phrase sonnerait vraiment bizarre si on avait conjugué le verbe au singulier.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat "ce genre de journalisme". Le Monde? Quel genre de journalisme serait meilleur? Cette section du journal Le Monde est intitulé CAMPUS, c'est pourquoi les pronoms son et ses sont utilisés. Il s'agit d'un site "D'aide aux étudiants". Et ceci explique cela, à mon avis...

Comment: @Lambie Je rencontre des abus de langages dans à peu près tous les types de journalismes, à part peut-être le journal officiel de l'Académie Française. Et je comprends pas la partie sur les pronoms, quel autres pronoms tu voudrais mettre ?

Comment: @Teleporting Goat Ah, oui, le son, ses c'était pour une autre question. Je ne vois pas pourquoi on parlerait d'abus de langage. Par contre, les syllepse, oui.

Comment: @Lambie Pas de souci ^^ J'ai dit "abus de langage" en référence au dernier lien seulement, pas à la syllepse.

Comment: Une syllepse, pour un verbe au pluriel alors que le sujet est grammaticalement *et sémantiquement* singulier ? Pour moi ça ne passe pas. Ce n'est pas une syllepse, c'est un accord au plus proche, et accorder le verbe avec un complément qui vient après, je trouve ceci absolument pas naturel.

Comment: @Gilles C'est bien une syllepse ^^ mais selon les gens ça peut sonner normal ou comme une erreur. Par définition c'est une erreur grammaticale de toute façon.